# Is it possible to have xrandr in different modes based on workspace?

Tags: xorg, xrandr, openbox, display, workspaces

Is it possible to have **xrandr** at **--right-of** the screen in workspace1 and **--same-as** at workspace2? (I'm using openbox)

If you interested why I want to do this:
I'm having a presentation and I need to show my slides at **--right-of** the screen while at the same time I have access to my slides notes in my own monitor. The other thing is: I need to switch between slides and my IDE, so I can write codes and describe what it does while both me an audience can see what's happening.

Comment: Can you make Openbox's workspace-switching command call `xrandr`? (I don't think there's another solution: the monitor configuration applies to a display, not to a workspace.)

Comment: Not perfectly, but it works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have a simple solution.
You can add a key binding to your 'rc.xml' that executes the `GoToDesktop` command and also execute the `xrandr` command.

Here is the example for the key combination <kbd>Windows key</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and it switches to desktop one and sets the monitors with `--same-as`.

```
<keybind key="W-F1">
    <action name="GoToDesktop"><to>1</to></action>
    <action name="Execute">
      <command>xrandr --output DP1-2 --same-as eDP1</command>
    </action>
</keybind>
```

Something similar can be done for Desktop two.

Sadly this only works when you press the specific key binding and not when you use another method for switching the desktop/workspace.